# Changing directory in bash for GNU

Tags: windows, linux, gnu

I have never worked with Linux and hence I am ignorant in the commands.However, I need to use the GNU for win64 environment for one of the programming tools to function. I have downloaded the GNU from cygwin.  This package includes gcc and various commands and 
     shells (sh, bash, etc.) that make the PC have a unix
     like environment.

I have to change to the directory of the program code MyPrograms and type "make all".
On opening the terminal of cygwin i get this line >> -bash-4.1$

Question is what is the command for changing to the directory MyPrograms;what do I type in after -bash-4.1$

Comment: `ls` to list and `cd <Directory Name>`?

Comment: To change directory use: "cd /directory_name" and for listing use "ls -al" to get full infromaton

Answer (score 2):

If your MyPrograms folder is located at C:\MyPrograms, then in Cygwin, type:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/MyPrograms
```

Refer to this [FAQ](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#windows)

Comment: The programs are written in C language [link] (http://www.kanungo.com/software/umdhmm-v1.02.README) and I am aware that in Linux we can efficiently do C programming and have the gcc compiler. But in this case, I can neither see an editor nor can I execute any programs. Kindly help how to go about this.

Comment: Refer to [this page](http://cygwin.com/install.html), you'd likely to install gcc and other tools separately. But I am not quite a Cygwin guy, due to the licensing terms it imposes. I was using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) tool set. [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) was what I used and worked almost flawlessly with Linux source compilation.